# Combine x-show & x-text toggle in alpine.js

Tags: web-frontend, alpine.js

I am new to alpine.js and i need to toggle the innerText of an element, does anyone know ho can i combine showing an element and changing the innerText of another element? here is my code

```html
<div x-data="{ numOrder: false, delNumOrder: 'Remove your order number' }">
  <button x-on:click="numOrder = !numOrder">
  Insert your order number</button>
  <input x-show="numOrder" type="text" placeholder="Order Number">
</div>
```

I need to overide the button text by **delNumOrder**, i have tried using **x-text** :

```html
<button x-on:click="numOrder = !numOrder" x-text="delNumOrder = !delNumOrder">
```

Can i use something like ?

```html
<div x-data="{ numOrder: false, delNumOrder = delNumOrder ? 'Insert your order number' : 'Remove your order number' }"></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an expression inside of `x-text`, in this case the ternary for the text: `numOrder ? 'Remove your order number': 'Insert your order number'`. You probably want to do something like the following:

```html
<div x-data="{ numOrder: false }">
  <button
    x-on:click="numOrder = !numOrder"
    x-text="numOrder ? 'Remove your order number': 'Insert your order number'"
  ></button>
  <input x-show="numOrder" type="text" placeholder="Order Number">
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, exactly ;-)

Comment: Just a note, ternary statements work best with boolean values or explicit truthy/falsy values. I was checking whether an empty object was falsy and it wasn't working because `[]` and `{}` are both truthy as outlined here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy